# How to stop reading input and analyze data in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I need to create a code in C that reads in a list of pairs of numbers with the first number being the product number (between 1 and and the total number of products as determined by the input) and the second number being the rating from 1-10 and stores it in a 2D array. The rows of the array starting at 1 are product numbers and columns 1-10 are ratings. Column 11 is total number of stars and column 12 is total number of ratings. I have to use scanf to read in the values, and when scan()!=2, the loops should stop and the report generated.

The report should list for each product the number of ratings for each value (i.e. 2 ratings of 5 stars, 17 ratings of 10 stars, etc.) as well as the average rating.

I think I have the logic correct and my code compiles but it keeps returning error when I try to generate a report. Any clues what the problem might be?

This is the code I have so far:

```
int productStar[][13] = {0};
int i = 0;
int product = 0;
int stars = 0;
int howMany = 0;
int ratings = 0;
float avg = 0;
int sum = 0;

printf("How many unique products?\n");
scanf("%d", &howMany);

printf("Please enter product # and stars\n");

while(1)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &product, &stars); /* Reads in two values; first is product number, second is rating */

    if (scanf("%d %d", &product, &stars) != 2) /* kills the loop */
    {
        printf("Hi from the inside\n");
        break;
    }


    productStar[product][stars] += 1; /* adds tally to specific product rating */

    productStar[product][11] += stars; /* increments total number of stars; used later to find avg */

    productStar[product][12] += 1; /* increments how many ratings */   

}

for (int product = 0; product <= howMany; ++product)
{
 for (int stars = 0; stars <= 10; ++stars)
    {
       avg = productStar[product][11]/productStar[product][12];

        printf("Product %d Information:\n", product);
        printf("1 star: %d\n", productStar[product][1]);
        printf("2 star: %d\n", productStar[product][2]);
        printf("3 star: %d\n", productStar[product][3]);
        printf("4 star: %d\n", productStar[product][4]);
        printf("5 star: %d\n", productStar[product][5]);
        printf("6 star: %d\n", productStar[product][6]);
        printf("7 star: %d\n", productStar[product][7]);
        printf("8 star: %d\n", productStar[product][8]);
        printf("9 star: %d\n", productStar[product][9]);
        printf("10 star: %d\n", productStar[product][10]);
        printf("Average rating: %2.2f out of 10 (%d ratings total).\n", avg, ratings);
        printf("--------------------\n");
    }
}

for (product = 0; product <= howMany; ++product)
{
    sum += productStar[product][12];
    /* Sum of all ratings */
}

printf("%d product ratings evaluated in all.\n\n", sum);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: All those `printf("1 star: %d\n", productStar[product][1]);` lines can be replaced with just one inside a for loop.

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?  I'm thinking it might have to do with your `int productStar[][13] = {0};` initialization...

Answer (score 0):

You're reading from standard input twice in a row which I don't think you want to do. Perhaps try changing the second `scanf` inside of you input reading loop to a statement that checks to see if product and stars are not empty strings:

```
  while(1) {
        scanf("%d %d", &product, &stars); /* Reads in two values; first is product number, second is rating */

        if (product == '\0' || stars == '\0') /* kills the loop */
        {
            // Break out of input loop and process data.
            break;
        }
  }

  // Processing code.
```

Also, it's a good idea to check for division by zero:

```
if (productStar[product][12] != 0) {
    avg = productStar[product][11]/productStar[product][12];
}
```

After I made those changes your code worked perfectly :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int productStar[][13] = {0};
int i = 0;
int product = 0;
int stars = 0;
int howMany = 0;
int ratings = 0;
float avg = 0;
int sum = 0;

int main(void) {
  printf("How many unique products?\n");
  scanf("%d", &howMany);

  printf("Please enter product # and stars\n");

  while(1)
  {


      scanf("%d %d", &product, &stars); /* Reads in two values; first is product number, second is rating */

      if (product == '\0' || stars == '\0') /* kills the loop */
      {
          break;
      }


      productStar[product][stars] += 1; /* adds tally to specific product rating */

      productStar[product][11] += stars; /* increments total number of stars; used later to find avg */

      productStar[product][12] += 1; /* increments how many ratings */

  }

  for (int product = 0; product <= howMany; ++product)
  {
   for (int stars = 0; stars <= 10; ++stars)
      {
        if (productStar[product][12] != 0) {
           avg = productStar[product][11]/productStar[product][12];
        }

          printf("Product %d Information:\n", product);
          printf("1 star: %d\n", productStar[product][1]);
          printf("2 star: %d\n", productStar[product][2]);
          printf("3 star: %d\n", productStar[product][3]);
          printf("4 star: %d\n", productStar[product][4]);
          printf("5 star: %d\n", productStar[product][5]);
          printf("6 star: %d\n", productStar[product][6]);
          printf("7 star: %d\n", productStar[product][7]);
          printf("8 star: %d\n", productStar[product][8]);
          printf("9 star: %d\n", productStar[product][9]);
          printf("10 star: %d\n", productStar[product][10]);
          printf("Average rating: %2.2f out of 10 (%d ratings total).\n", avg, ratings);
          printf("--------------------\n");
      }
  }



  for (product = 0; product <= howMany; ++product)
  {
      sum += productStar[product][12];
      /* Sum of all ratings */
  }

  printf("%d product ratings evaluated in all.\n\n", sum);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you get it to work? I'm finding that whenever I compile, certain values in the array aren't initialized to zero. Additionally, the code also isn't computing the averages.